# Sequelize: applying a where clause to a subquery

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to add a where clause to the subquery but I'm getting the error below. Is what I'm attempting to do not possible?

```
Error: Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed.

models.Message.findAll({
    attributes:  ['createdAt', 'content',
      [
        sequelize.literal(`
            RANK() OVER (
              PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT('createdAt', '%Y-%m-%d') 
              ORDER BY createdAt DESC
        )`),
        'ranked',
      ]],
      where: [sequelize.literal('ranked') <= 3]
  })
```

For reference is this the working MySql query that I'm attempting to replicate in sequelize.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        createdAt,
        content,
        RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(`createdAt`, '%Y-%m-%d') 
            ORDER BY createdAt DESC
            ) AS ranked 
    FROM
        communication_hub.Messages
    ORDER BY createdAt DESC
    ) AS messages
    WHERE ranked <= 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should use `sequelize.where` to combine `sequelize.literal` with some condition:

```
where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('ranked'), '<=',  3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! That got rid of `Error: Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed.`  However I'm now getting the error: `Unknown column 'ranked' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that `ranked` is not a real column. Then you can try the whole `RANK () ...` expression in `sequelize.where` instead of `ranked`

Comment: I assume this is what you're suggesting? `where: sequelize.where(sequelize.literal(`
                              RANK() OVER (
                                PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT('createdAt', '%Y-%m-%d') 
                                ORDER BY createdAt DESC)`), '<=',  3)`  If so, I get another new error: You cannot use the window function 'rank' in this context.'

Comment: Unfortunately, it says I cannot use rank function in this context

Comment: Ok, can you add a desired working SQL-query in your post so that we can look at what you try to achieve

Comment: Hmm. `SELECT` from `SELECT`. I don't how to achieve this through a model and not by using a plain SQL query. Can you simplify it by make it a simple SELECT?

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
where: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('ranked'), '<=',  3)
```

Comment: I tried this but, I get the error: `SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'ranked' in 'where clause'`

Comment: before ranked use model name with dot for example `where: sequelize.where(sequelize.col('modelName.ranked'), '<=',  3)`